# JQuery does not read the value properly even with quote

Tags: jquery

So I have this value from my database column:

```
\u25cf10:00-10:50 IELTS Listening Randy  change to \r\n(1) 09:00-09:50 Rose or (2)  11:00-11:50 Zel\r\n\u25cf16:00-16:50 Ed IELTS  Reading \r\n(1) 15:00-15:50 Jane or (2) 13:00-13:50 Rose\r\n\r\nMy class schedule on the system is wrong~ please kindly check it, thank you very much!\r\n\r\n
```

This value is from column named `Remark`

So I will show the data using JQuery `post` data and get the values of each columns, Other columns were fine but when I get into the `Remark` it shows like this: [image]

How did this happen? I tried `replace` but still does not work for me

Comment: Can you share the relevant code with us? And what is the error that the error is displaying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the line breaks - `\r\n`. The quick way to fix this is to use template literals as they can cope with line breaks:

```js
$('[name="form-remarks"]').val(`●10:00-10:50 IELTS Listening Randy  change to 
(1) 09:00-09:50 Rose or (2)  11:00-11:50 Zel
●16:00-16:50 Ed IELTS  Reading 
(1) 15:00-15:50 Jane or (2) 13:00-13:50 Rose

My class schedule on the system is wrong~ please kindly check it, thank you very much!

`);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 600px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="form-remarks"></textarea>
```

Note that this will not work in IE, though.

Alternatively you will need to replace the line breaks with a more suitable character, such as whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work, I have used backticks instead of quotes

```js
var data = `\u25cf10:00-10:50 IELTS Listening Randy  change to \r\n(1) 09:00-09:50 Rose or (2)  11:00-11:50 Zel\r\n\u25cf16:00-16:50 Ed IELTS  Reading \r\n(1) 15:00-15:50 Jane or (2) 13:00-13:50 Rose\r\n\r\nMy class schedule on the system is wrong~ please kindly check it, thank you very much!\r\n\r\n`

$('[name="form-remarks"]').val(data)
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="form-remarks"/>
```